# useState hook not updating in order ( The first render ) in REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I was working on a react  native project , and I keep facing an error while using useState Hook ! the useState update is not working in order ( before calling the function ' see the code ( setDistance' ) the console log is giving me 0 in the distance but I updated it after calling the function but if i click the button for the second time it shows me the distance

```
  const [distance, setDistance] = React.useState(0);

  const calculatePrice = () => {
    if (typee === "Motorcycle" && distance > 100) {
      setShowOptions(true);
      Alert.alert(
        "Chose another vehicle type",
        "Motocycle cannot more than 100km",
        [{ text: "Okay" }]
      );
      return;
    }
  };

 <View>
        <Button
          title="Calculate Price"
          onPress={() => {
            setDistance(
              calcCrow(
                depart.latitude,
                depart.longitude,
                destination.latitude,
                destination.longitude
              )
            );
            console.log(distance);
            console.log(typee);
            calculatePrice();
          }}
        />
      </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

SetState method does not update the state variable when it's called.

You may use useEffect hook with the state dependency to watch its changes.

I recommend you to pass distance as argument or calculate it on a useEffect hook.